# local javascript files going through zend_acl?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-acl

I have a strange issue after moving my zend web application to a linux server, when my layout tries to include a javascript file:-

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
 ->appendFile('/js/jquery/jquery.jqDock.min.js'); ?>
```

The code goes through my zend_acl factory:-

```
if($objAcl->isAllowed($role, $request->getModuleName() .'::'.$request->getControllerName() .'::' .$request->getActionName(), 'view')){
     //carry on with loading....
}
```

The request object looks like this:-

```
$request->module = 'ajfit'
$request->controller = 'js'
$request->action = 'jquery'
$request->_baseUri = '/js/jquery/jquery.jqDock.min.js'
```

When the above code is stepped over the application throws this exception:-

```
$ex->message = "Resource 'ajfit::js::jquery' not found"
```

I certainly know that i have not added this resource to my $objAcl zend_acl, and i know that i have not allowed access to it, and i don't want to. Thisis a local resource that exists in /public/js/jquery/ and should be bypassed and treated as a non-mvc resource.

When this application was running in windows it recognised that '/js/jquery/jquery.jqDock.min.js' was a local resource and did not go through zend_acl.

Am i missing something in my configuration, maybe a setting in my .htaccess file?

I'm pulling my hair out with this on.

Thanks.

Andrew

Comment: Are you getting the file when the ACL is disabled?

Comment: On the Linux system, does that file have the correct permissions and do the letter cases match since Linux filesystems are case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a problem with your .htaccess, do you have those lines?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If yes, is your apache configured to allow the usage of htaccess?